# Inline CSS commands do not work with H1 even when using !important

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why inline CSS doesn't work for H1s on our website. I know that there are CSS commands in place (on a stylesheet) but aren't they supposed to be overwritten by any inline CSS command?

I won't go into details as to why we want our H1s to look like normal texts (it's a long story). But basically, our goal is to enclose certain texts in H1 tags and make them look like normal texts. However it just wouldn't work no matter what even when using "!important". Here's my code:

`test <h1 style="display:inline !important; font-size:18px !important;">Beyond Reasonable Doubt and the Rush to Judgement</h1> test`

The system would not recognize this. I look at the source code of the rendered HTML and I see this:

```html
<p>test </p>
<h1 style="display: inline !important; font-size: 42.75px;" class="fittexted_for_content_h1">Beyond Reasonable Doubt and the Rush to Judgement</h1>
<p> test</p>
```

It doesn't make sense. Am I missing something? I simply want the H1 to look like normal and flow like normal texts, like this (inline and same font-size):

test Beyond Reasonable Doubt and the Rush to Judgement test

Additional Info:

We're using Wordpress and this is how it looks now on the backend:

[image]

And yet if I look at the source code of what's rendered, this is what shows up:

[image]

Comment: What should be the effect of having an inline element surrounded by block elements?

Comment: Editing it inline in the code inspector does change the font-size for me. Is the problem that your code is not being pushed through permanently to the development build?

Comment: They are supposed to look the same (formatting the same). The surrounding elements are not supposed to be blocked as they all should be in a single sentence/paragraph. I don't know why the system automatically inserts the <p> tags. I don't really know what's the problem but my CSS codes are correct, right? So perhaps it's a system issue (Wordpress)?

Comment: If you add `style="display: inline"` to the `<p>` tags as well (you don't need `!important`) you get these three elements on the same line. Sorry but browser works with the HTML received from the server, not the one meant to be sent ;-)

Comment: So some code you aren't showing us is wrapping the text nest to the h1 in paragraphs. We don't know what that code is. There isn't much we can do to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your H1 element is inline, but the P-elements are still blocks. If you make them inline, you'll see the difference. Not sure about the font-size though. That seems to be working fine for me.

Edit: I may have misread the question. The snippet shows the rendered result, not what you're using in your code. Some kind of renderer/sanitizer probably won't accept plain text and wraps a p-tag arround it. If the rendered content is not what you want, then maybe more information is needed about what is used to render the html.
You could still use css to make the P-element behave inline, using the same `display: block` as well of course. Probably you need to wrap the text in p-tags yourself first so you can add custom style tags. My guess is that whatever renderer is used won't wrap p-elements in another p-element as that would be invalid html.

Edit2:
Since your custom code contains `font-size:18px !important` and the rendered result contains `font-size: 42.75px`, it is almost certain your code is overwritten by whichever renders the final output. If you have no control over that, you might be able to achieve it using (non-inline) style:

```
<style>
    .fittexted_for_content_h1 {
        font-size: 18px !important;
    }
</style>
```

(you might want to use a more specific selector to prevent affecting the style somewhere else)

Edit3: Now that is clear that Wordpress is used it makes some sense. Wordpress does remove/overwrite certain input. I'm no expert in Wordpress, but I'm sure answers can be found when searching for things like 'Wordpress removes/changes inline style' or 'adding custom style in Wordpress'

Comment: Actually I did this using a specific selector but it wouldn't work - which is why I resorted to inline CSS. You nailed it when you said that "it is almost certainly your code is overwritten". But that's what confuses me. Inline CSS should overwrite anything, right? But in this case it just won't.

Comment: You're correct that inline CSS should overwrite other styles, but with being overwritten I meant that your code is overwritten, which isn't html/css behavior. It can only be done by some kind of renderer or parser that alters your code. 

It is strange that you say using a specific selector doesn't work. I just tested it by adding the style (in devtools), which worked for me. Could it be that when you add style in your code, that this is being removed by the renderer?

Comment: Super thanks! It worked!! I did try assigning a specific selector before but I tried a different class instead of "fittexted_for_content_h1" (thinking that this class is used in other parts of the website and I don't want to mess with the formatting of that). That different class wouldn't work. But then I realized that we really use no other H1s with the class "fittexted_for_content_h1" and so I'm free to use it as a selector for this one. I did and that worked! Thank you again!

Comment: Additional info (in case there are concerns with complications): Any H1 we put on the body seems to have this class by default though (fittexted_for_content_h1). So I know there will be complications if we choose to use H1 again with a different formatting in the future. Once that happens, we'll deal with the renderer/parser issue :D

Comment: I'm to glad to hear it worked out :) 
If the class of H1 is automatically set/replaced by Wordpress, then you might work be able to arround this by wrapping the H1 in a div that uses a custom class or id, so you can target the specific H1 you want.

Comment: You're the best! I tried that one out and it worked! I encountered some issues which are likely due to our use of shortcodes in implementing the content but that is a different topic (and which I think can be easily addressed on the side). But this one definitely worked without needing to modify the CSS for "fittexted_for_content_h1", thus eliminating possible future complications. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have the following:

```
block
inline
block
```

If you want the 3 to be one next to the other you need to display the `p` as an inline element as well. Alternatively, you can also do this:

```
<p>Hello <h1>Huge</h1> World </p>
```

This way you will have the 3 words one next to the other without altering their display properties.

Comment: I added <p> to the surrounding texts and displayed them inline. That worked. But the font-size is still a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use `!important`, inline styles have the highest priority and will override any other styles. Second, the `<p>` tags are still blocks, so they will display as such. You need to change your code and specify those as inline or inline blocks:

```html
<p style="display: inline">test </p>
<h1 style="display: inline; font-size: 18px;" class="fittexted_for_content_h1">Beyond Reasonable Doubt and the Rush to Judgement</h1>
<p style="display: inline"> test</p>
```

That'll do it.

Comment: I did this and it worked for the display. But the font-size remains a mystery.

Comment: I just changed the font size to 18px. It seems to be working here. If it's not working on your site, then something's happening that changes the font size before the html renders. That's another issue entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Seems like another issue entirely indeed.